# tool for webcam effects

Tags: webcam, effects

Using Skype, I have the option to blur out the background on my webcam. I'm now using Zoom and Google Meeting a lot more and would love to apply a similar filter in other apps.
I've looked around for webcam filters / effects here but most posts are from nearly a decade ago.

Are there any current 3rd party tools that can put up some useful filters in any application?

Answer (score 1):

`webcamoid` is available in the universe repository for all recent Ubuntu versions.

It can be installed with

```
sudo apt install webcamoid
```

Features:

- Take pictures and record videos with the webcam.
- Manages multiple webcams.
- GUI interface.
- Custom controls for each webcam.
- Add funny effects to the webcam.
- +60 effects available.
- Effects with live previews.
- Translated to many languages.
- Use custom network and local files as capture devices.
- Capture from desktop.
- Many recording formats.
- Virtual webcam support for feeding other programs.

[webcamoid on GitHub](https://github.com/webcamoid/webcamoid)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually tried this app and it doesn't have the effects I was looking for. My main interest is an effect that either replaces the background or blurs it out. I've seen this in the past for several apps but it is not available (that I see) in webcamoid.

Comment: i was looking for blur effect background ... and wasn't into webcamoid

Comment: Pity the package has bad qt linkage :(

Comment: Whenever I start webcamoid, it crashes immediately with segmentation fault.

Comment: @user1768761 Then contact the maintainer of the package (file a bug report) so they can fix this instead of downvoting  here which does not helpy you.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you wish with webcamoid, do light yourself over a darker background and add a "replace color" effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install OBS Studio from the [official PPA](https://obsproject.com/download#linux).
2. Install the [background-removal](https://github.com/occ-ai/obs-backgroundremoval) plugin.
3. Open OBS and add a video capture source for your camera.
4. Add the "Background removal" filter to your camera source. [See the documentation](https://occ-ai.github.io/obs-backgroundremoval/usage)
5. Start the virtual camera in OBS. See the [OBS documentation](https://obsproject.com/kb/virtual-camera-guide) about the virtual camera.
6. In another program that wants to use your camera switch the camera source to the "Obs Virtual Camera"